# Java stack peek

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

Hey all, was wondering something about Java Stacks. Does peek() return a reference to the actual object on the top of the stack or a copy of the object? For instance, if I ran the following code:

```
Stack.peek().setName("name");
```

Would this modify the *name* field of the object currently at the top of the stack, or to a completely different object with identical values for all it's fields?

Comment: Note that the Javadoc of the Stack class states, that a Deque (e.g. ArrayDeque) should be used in preference to the Stack class:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since peek returns a reference to an object it would be modified.

Answer (score 8):

In general, very few bits of code in Java go round arbitrarily creating copies of objects. `peek` will return the *reference* that's on the top of the stack... don't forget that the *objects* aren't on the stack in the first place, only the references.

So in your example, you would indeed modify the name of the object that the *reference* on the stack refers to.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely the reference. It will change the name.

Answer (score 1):

In http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html I see no evidence of why it would return a copy, so I really think it will change the original